# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined(DOM)

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I installed rx dom through
npm install rx-dom
and cloning through git hub with command: git clone https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rxjs-dom.git
I used this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx-dom
A folder named 'rx-dom' is created in my original folder
But DOM still remains undefined in my index.js file. I cannot figure out why DOM still remains undefined.

This is my index.js file:

```
const Rx =require('rx');
function initialize() {
      var quakes = Rx.Observable
      .interval(5000) .flatMap(function() {
      return Rx.DOM.jsonpRequest({
      url: QUAKE_URL,
      jsonpCallback: 'eqfeed_callback'
      }); })
      .flatMap(function(result) {
      return Rx.Observable.from(result.response.features);
      })
      .distinct(function(quake) { return quake.properties.code; });
      quakes.subscribe(function(quake) {
      var coords = quake.geometry.coordinates; var size = quake.properties.mag * 10000;
          L.circle([coords[1], coords[0]], size).addTo(map);
        });
      }
Rx.DOM.ready().subscribe(initialize);
```

Comment: add your app.js and index.js codes

Comment: There is no app.js file.  Its only index.js file which uses DOM that I have uploaded.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.